# Xamarin Live Player Errors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have created the default Xamarin project, works fine connected to a Mac -> build -> view in simulator on Mac, but when I try and run the Live Payer from Visual Studio I get the following errors:

```
\Services\MockDataStore.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\App.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Services\MockDataStore.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\ViewModels\AboutViewModel.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\ViewModels\BaseViewModel.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\ViewModels\ItemsViewModel.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\AboutPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\AboutPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\ItemDetailPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\ItemDetailPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\Views\NewItemPage.xaml.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And on and on it goes, these files are all in the Shared project.

Anyone have issue similar?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17560/error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-xamarin-could-not-be-found

Comment: That thread is useless, no actual answers just people having a similar issue for years.

Answer (score 2):

If it's any consolation, I have exactly the same problem. Here's what I've done to try and resolve the issue, currently with partial success:

1. Deinstall/reinstall Visual Studio 2017 Community Preview
2. Deinstall/install Visual Studio Community - the current release
3. Created a new Windows 10 VM and installed Visual Studio Community 2017 current release

Based on action point #3, I don't believe the cause if anything specific to my installation however I'm then surprised that the issue is not more widespread.

**UPDATE (18th Dec):** I downloaded an existing example project (https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/LivePlayer/LiveView/) and had some success. The app now runs on my phone via Live Player however I now get a MONO debugger error, which I'm currently investigating.

Answer (score 0):

as of now :
Custom Renderers are not supported.
Effects are not supported.
Custom Controls with Custom Bindable Properties are not supported.
Embedded resources are not supported (ie. embedding images or other resources in a PCL).
Third party MVVM frameworks are not supported (ie. Prism, Mvvm Cross, Mvvm Light, etc.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations